# Given a set of integer sets S, find the smallest possible set of integers X so that every set in S contains at least one integer also in X

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of integer sets S, find the smallest possible set of integers X so that every set in S contains at least one integer also in X.

The smallest set is defined by the set with the lowest cardinality (least number of elements), and if there are multiple sets with the same smallest cardinality, then the smallest set is the set that comes first lexicographically (for example, (1, 3, 6) comes before (1, 4, 5))

For example, if S is:

```
{
(4,7)
(7,10)
(4, 15, 18)
(7, 10, 18)
(4, 7, 15, 18)
(7, 10, 18)
}
```

The smallest possible cardinality for X is 2. Possible sets for X sorted lexicographically with cardinality 2 are: (4,7), (4, 10), (7, 15), (7, 18). Since (4,7) comes earliest it is the solution for X.

What algorithm should be used to solve this problem within a reasonable amount of time?

Some constraints on the input data are as follows:

- Every integer will be between 1 to 20
- S will contain at most 100 sets
- Every integer will be in at least 2 sets in S
- Integer sets will always be in increasing order

Comment: Possible duplicate? (though technically not in SO..) http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr.

Comment: We can help with homework; but will not do it for you. And especially, we won't solve a task where the extent of your involvement was copy-pasting it. Please post some reasonable attempt at the task, identifying a specific obstacle or problem that is stopping you from executing it. (Note that the linked question is, actually, a question, unlike yours: "Is there a general name for this problem? Is there an accepted “best” algorithm for finding the set M?")

Comment: In an RDBMS, for instance, you would simply arrange the sets by cardinality, and perhaps a group_concatenated result ordered lexicographically, and pick the first

Comment: Looking at my earlier comment, this is a [Hitting Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation) problem.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov This looks to be what I was looking for. I'll have to read through it to make sure, but I think that's what I need. Thanks, I was having trouble finding the right name for the algorithm so I could look it up.

Comment: @Amadon "What algorithm should be used to solve this problem within a reasonable amount of time?" Is in my question, I'm pretty sure that's a question asking for an algorithm that solves the problem. 

Additionally, not only is this not homework, but why would I add a bunch of information on what I've already tried when it's not relevant to the question? If you're curious, I considered using greedy, but that will almost definitely not work. Bruteforce might work since you would only need to test 2^20 different possible sets due to the 20 different integer constaint, but I think it needs DP

Comment: @shapiroyaacov The hitting set problem was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I was having a lot of trouble finding the right name for the problem, if you want to post it as an answer I can mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a question in [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr), it seems this question is asked there.
This is actually a [Hitting Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation) problem. It is formally a NP hard problem, but given some info about the expected input, some tweaks are usually possible.